# Pandas dataframe best line fitting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, curve-fitting

Hi I have the following dataset:

```
A = [1,10,23,45,24,25,55,67,73,26,13,96,53,23,24,43,90, 49], 
B = [24,23,29, BW,49,59,72, BW,9,183,17,12,2,49,BW,479,18,BW]
```

I want to fit straight lines in between 'BW' with A column in the x axis and store the slope values in new column C.
That is slope 1 is obtained by using [1,10,23] as x values and [24,23,29] as y values. Slope 2 is obtained using [24,25,55] as x values and [49,59,72] as y values. This continues until the end of the data frame.
Expected output will be:

```
C = [slope1, np.nan, np.nan, BW, slope2, np.nan, np.nan, BW, slope3,np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan, BW, slope4, np.nan, BW]
```

Also, is there a way I can show these lines in a graph? I am new in this and have no idea. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'between' BW? Also, you might want to rephrase your question so it is easier to understand.

Comment: I meant the values in columns B in between the occurrence of certain text 'BW'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the 'BW' locations and then split your arrays in these indexes. Here is a sample of you could do that:

```py
from pprint import pprint

import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

colors = list(mcolors.TABLEAU_COLORS.values())

A = [1, 10, 23, 45, 24, 25, 55, 67, 73, 26, 13, 96, 53, 23, 24, 43, 90, 49]
B = [24, 23, 29, 'BW', 49, 59, 72, 'BW', 9,
     183, 17, 12, 2, 49, 'BW', 479, 18, 'BW']


index = [k for k, value in enumerate(B) if value == 'BW']
index = [-1] + index + [len(B)]

slopes = []

for k in range(len(index)-1):
    x = A[index[k]+1:index[k+1]]
    y = B[index[k]+1:index[k+1]]

    if len(x) == 0:
        continue

    [slope, offset] = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    slopes.append(slope)

    reg_x = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 10)
    reg_y = slope*reg_x + offset

    plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color=colors[k], label=f'Group {k}')
    plt.plot(reg_x, reg_y, color=colors[k])

pprint(slopes)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

As slopes vector the result is

```
[0.24386920980926416,
 0.5977443609022566,
 -0.9183274470232099,
 -9.808510638297868]
```

And the plot:
[image: sample plot]

Maybe this is not the most elegant or pythonic way to solve this, but gets the job done

Comment: Is it possible to have goodness of fit (R2) value in each cases?

Comment: yeah, sure. Inside the loop the x and y data are already separated in chunks, so you could use the scipy function for linear regression [scipy.stats.linregress](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html), which already returns the correlation coefficient.

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved two months long problem for me.